# Post-Story Activities

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Are there any significant Post-Story dungeons or quest that are worth doing. I feel as though the game is over aside from some quest cleanup. Is there any specific extremely challenging dungeons or quests?

For example, in Torchlight the Dungeon went on infinitley and scaled as such. So building your skills and gear mattered to see how far down you can go. This game doesn't seem to have any sort of challenge like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is dungeon named "Primordia" that unlocks once you beat the game.

Is it significant or worth it, though? My vote is a definite "no". It's tiny and the only real purpose is to deliver the chicken joke shown in the above video.

Comment: I am so glad I built up this character so that I can kill chickens lol. I am a little saddened by the longevity of this game.

Answer (score 0):

There is another DLC now, it has the House of Valor that has many hard to do challenges. It is (I guess) the best thing you can do when you want to random kill everything at the end of the game because you liked it. But yes, it costs money (10€ in Europe).